# Outlook wont preview ics file created by ical4j

Tags: java, outlook, sendgrid, icalendar, ical4j

When sending ics attachments created by ical4j via sendgrid to an outlook user they aren't able to "preview" the invite. It recognizes that the attachment exists but claim "This file cannot be previewed because there is no previewer installed for it". https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdyvJ.png

However, I'm able to manually open the attachment and add the event to my outlook calendar.

I've been referencing these questions for guidance: 
[Sending Outlook meeting requests without Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461889/sending-outlook-meeting-requests-without-outlook)
[ics file not recognized by outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928264/ics-file-not-recognized-by-outlook)

As well as this PDF which details how outlook handles the ics format: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463911%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Heres an example of my current headers and ics structure:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20190726T182558Z
DTSTART:20190802T130000
DTEND:20190802T131500
SUMMARY:Company coaching review - ev_manager_1 user & ev_test_3 admin
UID:comapny-coaching-review-22
DESCRIPTION:ev_manager_1 user will coach ev_test_3 admin
SEQUENCE:0
CREATED:20190726T182558Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20190726T182558Z
PRODID:-//CompanyName//Coaching Corner//EN
CLASS:PRIVATE
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=3Dtext/html: /* Some properly formatted html here */
ORGANIZER:mailto:anthonyp4312@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=3DREQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=3Dev_manager_1 user:mailto:anthonyp4312@=
gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=3DREQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=3Dev_test_3 admin:mailto:anthonyp4312@=
gmail.com
LOCATION:ev_manager_1 user's desk
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I'm creating and sending the email itself using sendgrid like so.

```
    mail.addContent(Content("text/plain", emailContent.bodyPlainText))
    mail.addContent(Content("text/html", emailContent.bodyHTMl))
    mail.addContent(Content("text/calendar; method=REQUEST", emailContent.event))
```

I'm also including the ics file as an attachment as well as inline as shown above.

Basically, I need to somehow get outlook to correctly render that ics file correctly, and I'm not sure whats incorrect about this structure.

Comment: Being able to open and providing a preview are two very different things.

Comment: Please provide the full MIME message with all the body parts and including the top headers (multipart/alternative,...)

Comment: I have the same problem. I wish someone had provided a solution.